# How to implement renderer with respect to CPU capabilities

Tags: javascript, rendering, cpu

I was wondering what is the best way to implement a renderer in JavaScript. It's not the content part of the rendering that's really important here - I would rather like to hear when and how to effectively run the renderer code.

Currently, I have `window.setInterval(renderFunc, 1000 / 20)`, which will just render a frame each 50 ms (i.e., fps = 20).

The point is that faster computers won't render more frames, moreover slower computers will not be able to catch up with 20 fps, so the function is called more than the computer might be able to handle.

I was thinking of a `while(true)` loop, but this uses 100% CPU and will freeze the computer itself - so actually my game (the renderer is of my 3D game) won't be playable anymore at all since you cannot click on buttons anymore.

What is the most efficient option in this scenario, or is there a better method that has not come to my mind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could time how long a frame render takes, and adjust frame spacing to achieve an acceptable load. E.g., if your current frame took 5ms to render, and you want 50% load, wait 5ms before the next frame. You'll want to put some sanity checks on it, and also probably use times from the last several frames.

Comment: I like your idea, but on the other hand it also depends on other applications running. Most games have a changing fps each second depending on the current CPU power that's available at that specific moment.

Comment: @pimvdb: Well, there is indeed a tradeoff between instantly slows down (and thus a tiny blip causes frame rate to plummet) and being instantly responsive to higher load... that would be tunable by the amount of history to average in. Other than that, I'm not sure what you're saying; CPU power available (at a specific instant) is either 0% or 100%: you are either scheduled that timeslice or you're not. (Ignoring CPU frequency scaling here)

Comment: I basically meant that the Task Manager on Windows shows a number between 0% and 100% usage of CPU. When I start other applications which absorb CPU power, there is left available for the game with the effect of a lower fps of the game (and a bigger percentage in Task Manager). I could just measure the CPU usage when loading the game, but as a result it might become too high when, after some time, other applications are running as well.

Comment: @pimvdb: Well, that's the beauty of using recent frame timings. If your system's load goes up, the amount of time to render a frame does as well (assuming your frame rendering is a good percentage of the load), so you automatically lower the frame rate.

Comment: Yes - I could of course measure every second so as to opt for the best amount of frames to render. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a feature that is made specifically for animation, called `window.requestAnimationFrame`. This means that the browsers chooses when to call your animation function instead of you hardcoding intervals. Lots of benefits from using it:

- Faster computers will get higher frame rates
- Windows/tabs that aren't visible are updated much less often
- Varying frame rate depending on CPU usage

This article explains how to use it in a cross browser fashion:
http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

The article also links to http://jsfiddle.net/paul/XQpzU/2/

Comment: This really looks extremely interesting!

Comment: It seems not to be available on Chrome, whilst I'm making the game to be Chrome-only... That's a pity.

Comment: The jsFiddle example works fine in Chrome... oops, no it doesn't... it's using the backup method, trying to get 60 fps with setTimeout

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the latest Chromium builds contain the webkit version - see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64848. It's just not yet available in Google Chrome.

Comment: However, `setInterval` is much smoother in my opinion, in Chrome at least.

Answer (score 1):

Look into trying the `while(true)` loop inside of a web worker thread. This should prevent the browser from locking up. Note that you can't directly manipulate a `<canvas>` or any other part of the DOM from within the worker thread.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers

Comment: It looks certainly interesting, thank you. However, won't `while(true)` still use full CPU power this way?

Comment: That depends on how you define full CPU power. A thread can only utilize one core of the CPU, so unless you're running a Pentium 4 or something, this shouldn't be a huge issue. You can also use some sort of metric to determine how small of an interval to use in a `setInterval` call.

Comment: Just on a side note, is it possible at all to get current CPU usage with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

"setInterval() will pass the number of milliseconds late the callback was called"
 -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

You could use this to dynamically adjust your interval time.

N.B. MDC docs are for Javascript as implemented by Mozilla, not ECMA Script or other implementations. You should check if this works in other browsers.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion, but that's basically a check on a per-load basis, so to say, whilst the CPU might be used more and less during gameplay by other applications. I *could* also measure every so many seconds, but that's not very practical I guess.