# Bad smoothness webkitRequestAnimationFrame vs setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, animation, webkit, html5-canvas

With regard to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121326/how-to-implement-renderer-with-respect-to-cpu-capabilities) of mine, I tried out Chromium's support of `webkitRequestAnimationFrame`. Although it would have a bunch of advantages, it turned out to be much worse for me than using plain `setInterval` / `setTimeout` for generating an animation.

I tried the example stated on http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/, both with `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` and with `setTimeout`:

1. `webkitRequestAnimationFrame`: http://jsfiddle.net/hnQYt/
2. `setTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/hnQYt/2/

Am I the only person having issues with the smoothness of the first method? If not, how come this specially designed method fails miserably?

Comment: Try creating a [JS Performance test](http://jsperf.com), because the problem may just be with your particular version. EDIT: Which it is, as said by your answer.

Comment: @Amaan: Thanks but as I posted it was solved already; it's working just fine since then.

Comment: Yeah, noticed that just after I'd posted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest nightly build solved this issue - I guess it was a bug which is now fixed.